# Линия между border и outline в input[type=text]

Tags: css

Если `input[type=text]`, у которого в качестве фона установлен какой-то цвет, например `bacground:#ddd`. После нажатия на кнопку, её рамка стаёт чёрной. При попытке выяснить, `border` ли это, или `outline`, оказалось, что ни то, ни другое — это что-то между ними.

Пример  блока с `border` и `outline`:

[image: пример текстового поля с border и outline после нажатия] ([код](http://jsfiddle.net/9283M/))

Наблюдается исключительно в браузере `Opera`. Что это может быть?

Comment: это outline для псевдокласса :focus.  

ЗЫ с фидлом было бы проще

Comment: `Yura Ivanov`, я тоже так подумал, но, убрав `outline` для всех псевдоклассов `input` ничего не поменялось

Comment: @Crasher добавьте `outline-offset: -2px;` заработает.

Comment: @yura-ivanov, работает, но без `outline` не подойдёт. Без `outline` интересует в первую очередь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну тут вариантов не много, причем в разных браузерах оно по-разному работает.
Если нужен outline, тогда двигаем outline-offset (это расстояние между outline и border) на -1 или -2 пикселя. Если не нужен, тогда делаем outline однопиксельным одного цвета с border и двигаем outline-offset на -1px, бордер делаем меньше на 1px.
Вопрос "как сделать так чтоб было как я хочу и при этом не так как работает" - это браузерописателям.
ЗЫ Да и следует заметить, что убирая у элемента с фокусом эту рамку, ухудшается accessibility, об этом тоже надо помнить.

Comment: Тут вопрос слегка в другом — "почему не работает так, как было бы логично". В любом случае получается "костыль", скрывающий недостаток понимания `offset` данным браузером.

Спасибо за ответ.